# ¿Cómo agregar la sentencia track by en la directiva ng-repeat de mi aplicación?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, ng-repeat

Tengo que agregar la sentencia track by en la directiva ng-repeat para reducir los problemas de rendimiento, mi archivo .jsp contiene lo siguiente:

```
   <tr data-ng-repeat="item in (result=(users | filter:searchComplete | orderBy: ord: ordStatus))"
                                data-ng-if="$index >= (currentPage * pageSize) &&  $index<((currentPage+1)*pageSize)">
                                <td class="text-center" >{{$index+1}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{item.username}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{item.name}}&nbsp;{{item.lastname}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{item.email}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{item.position.name}}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">
```

Cómo debería agregar  la sentencia track by?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Porque tienes que agregarla?

Comment: Para reducir los problemas de rendimiento, eh editado la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: deberias usar el identificador de cada objeto de tu lista, suponiendo que es user.id seria algo como: data-ng-repeat="item in (result=(users | filter:searchComplete | orderBy: ord: ordStatus)) track by item.Id"

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que `username` es un propiedad unica para cada item, la utilizarias en `track by` al final de la expresión de la siguiente forma:

```
data-ng-repeat="item in (result=(users | filter:searchComplete | orderBy: ord: ordStatus)) track by item.username"
```